# Failed to resolve artifact. Missing: ---------- 1) org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, vaadin, maven-plugin

I want to use the addon vaadin Timeline, so I have to make the `gwt-maven-plugin 3.1` and my pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>life</groupId>
<artifactId>life</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>life Portlet</name>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <vaadin-widgets-dir>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</vaadin-widgets-dir>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                <liferayVersion>6.1.0</liferayVersion>
                <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Compiles your custom GWT components with the GWT compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                <!--modules> .. </modules -->
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <runTarget>clean</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <port>8080</port>
                <soyc>false</soyc>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Updates Vaadin 6.2+ widgetset definitions based on project dependencies -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                        <!-- <modules> <module>${package}.gwt.MyWidgetSet</module> </modules> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        gwt-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1.0-1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        vaadin-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            update-widgetset
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-timeline-agpl-3.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- sqx -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsh</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>jboss</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-backport-concurrent</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1.0.GA</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.sql</groupId> <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0</version> </dependency> -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.portal.portletcontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-m4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.4-702.jdbc3</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- sl4j-api-1.5.0 manquante -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId> <artifactId>spring-modules-jbpm31</artifactId> 
        <version>0.9</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- this is the dependency to the "jar"-subproject -->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<!-- Define our plugin repositories -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Codehaus</id>
        <name>Codehaus Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/mojo</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <url>[http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots]</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>demoiselle.sourceforge.net</id>
        <name>Demoiselle Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/release</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

But  when I do `mvn clean install` to build my project, the console shows me this error:

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT' in repository demoiselle.sourceforge.net (http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/release)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT

 Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DartifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -    Dversion=1.3-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

 Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DartifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.3-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
1) com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.1
2) org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT

 ----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
 com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
   demoiselle.sourceforge.net (http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/release),
   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
   Codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/mojo),
   codehaus-snapshots ([http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots]),
   vaadin-snapshots (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/),
   vaadin-releases (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-releases/),
   vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons)
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to previous answers: I don't see a reason for putting `gwt-maven-plugin` dependency inside `pluginManagement` unless it's defined in your parent POM. Even in the [Using Vaadin with Maven](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Vaadin%20with%20Maven) article there's no such thing as `pluginManagement`.

You are obviously using quite recent version of Vaadin (6.7.0) so the old plugins won't work with it. Try these:

- The most important: Change `vaadin-maven-plugin` to 1.0.2
- Change `gwt-maven-plugin` version to 2.3.0-1
- Change `gwt-user` dependency version to 2.3.0

If the fixes above won't work, try creating a fresh Vaadin project by calling:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=exampleArtifact -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=war
```

and compare the POM structure and plugin versions to your own.

Comment: Just wanted to point out, I was having this issue and was using `vaadin-maven-plugin` 1.0.1 which refers to a snapshot version of other plugins who don't exist anymore. Changing the version number to 1.0.2 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since gwt-maven-plugin is up to version 2.4.0 its quite possible that this particular snapshot does not exist anymore ...

Try locking the dependency version to something similar, i.e. 1.3.1:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the gwt-maven-plugin within a pluginManagement block instead in the build area. As far as i understand the gwt-maven-plugin will be used by an other otherwise i wouldn't understand your output. Furthermore never rely on SNAPSHOT releases of plugins. Fix your versions of your plugins to get realiable results in your build. And last but not least start using a repository manager (Artifactory, Archive, Nexus) to get rid of the repository definitions in your pom. Makes life earsier.